# How to nest git repositories?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a parent git repo which contains files common to my product. Now when I deploy I will need to add customizations based on the client I'm deploying for. The customizations lie at different parts of the parent structure as different sub-folders (a 'feature' of the framework I'm forced to use). Is it possible to split my repo into 'parent-repo', 'client1-customization', 'client2-customization' etc.

To make it clear:
My directory structure is as below:

```
myproject
-- .git
-- web
   -- client1
   -- client2
   -- common
-- lib
```

I want it as:

```
myproject
-- .git
-- web
   -- client1
      -- .git
   -- client2
      -- .git
   -- common
--lib
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you use submodules. See the [git community book](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for details.

Answer (score 2):

[Ayende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366) shared some experience about this topic and recommends [git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) over submodules

see below for further reference:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/01/10/the-problem-with-git-submodules.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/01/10/git-subtree.aspx

Comment: It really depends on your use case. When the subdirectory will be developed as part of your project, then yes, subtree merging is often better. However, when it's simply a component you plug in, and update from time to time, submodules really shine.